# After sending discord heartbeat client closes connection while discord responds with 4002 error code

Tags: kotlin, discord, okhttp, gateway

So I'm creating simple discord bot in Kotlin using OkHttp3 but I can't seem to properly send a discord heartbeat opcode. On Discord Developer Documentation I saw example heartbeat payload and it looked like this `{ "op": 1, "d": 251 }`

So I tried to send my version of this (d is my sequence number). After sending the heartbeat WebSocket closes the connection with error code 4002 which corresponds to `Decode error`

Comment: We need your code please